# How can I add footnotes to my bib entries?

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

I would like to add footnotes to my bib file entries to provide some additional information such as "the authors are listed alphabetically" at the bottom of the page, where the references appear. For example, I want to have something like this:

```
  title={blahblah},
  author={A, A and B\footnote{the authors are listed alphabetically}, B},
  journal={J},
  pages={1-2},
  year={2022},
  publisher={Publisher}}
```

Comment: Interesting question, but I think you should never do this. You can add information about the reference in the note field, and the style you use may allow or disallow it. Your example of using a footnote to explain the reference style rules may just be hypothetical, but if not, you definitely don't need a footnote to explain the reference format. This is why people use standard reference formats... you don't need to explain them.

Comment: I need this for my CV document. I agree that it is a matter of style/preference. As styles are quiet about notes that can be repetitive (for example, I have multiple papers that have alphabetically-ordered authors), I would prefer to mention it once and use footnotes on my papers to refer to that note.

Comment: You might try \string\footnote.  It is after all a separate file.

Comment: Instead of using a footnote, I would suggest that at the _start_ of the publications section of your CV, add a line like _In entries marked by daggers, authors are listed alphabetically and not in order of contribution._ and then replace `\footnote` with a superscripted dagger symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged `biblatex`, you can actually store the data more semantically  in your `.bib` file, and adjust its display with conditionals. For CVs I also think it is easier for the readers if you put the symbols on the item label.

Here's an example to get you started.

`testbib.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\llap{\textsuperscript{\showAuthorInfo}}[#1]}
\NewDocumentCommand\showAuthorInfo{}{\ifkeyword{alphabetical}{$\dagger$}{}\ifkeyword{corr}{c}{}}


\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\begin{document}

\title{CV for B}

\maketitle


\section{Publications}

\textit{(For entries marked with daggers, author list is alphabetical and does not reflect contribution. For entries marked with the letter ``c'', I am the corresponding author.)}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`testbib.bib`:

```
@ARTICLE{art1,
   author = {A, A and B, B},
   title = {title},
   journal = {\mbox{G-Animal's} Journal},
   year = 1986,
   volume = 41,
   number = 7,
   keywords = {alphabetical}
}

@ARTICLE{art2,
   author = {B, B and C, C},
   title = {title},
   journal = {\mbox{G-Animal's} Journal},
   year = 1988,
   volume = 41,
   number = 7,
}

@ARTICLE{art3,
   author = {D, D and B, B},
   title = {title},
   journal = {\mbox{G-Animal's} Journal},
   year = 1982,
   volume = 41,
   number = 7,
   keywords = {corr}
}

@ARTICLE{art4,
   author = {A, A and B, B and Z, Z},
   title = {title},
   journal = {\mbox{G-Animal's} Journal},
   year = 1990,
   volume = 41,
   number = 7,
   keywords = {alphabetical, corr}
}
```

Output:

[image]